# Django Migrations - how to insert just one model?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I just made a mess in my local Django project and realized that somehow I'm out of sync with my migrations. I tried to apply `initial` and realized that some of the tables already exist, so I tried `--fake`. This made the migration pass, but now I'm missing the one table I just wanted to add... how can I prepare migration just for one model or make Django re-discover what my database is missing and create that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a `models` directory. Adding an import of the model to `__init__.py` allowed me to control whether it's visible to makemigrations or not. I found that using `strace`.